# Создание инсталяционого пакета

Tags: установка, лицензирование, windows, c#

Здравствуйте!

Могли бы подсказать как решить следующую задачу.

Мне необходимо создать инсталяционный пакет для Windows-приложения, который будет находиться на диске. На компьютер программа должна будет устанавливаться только один раз. На завершающем этапе мастера необходимо будет провести активацию для установленной программы. Это будет LiveID  и соответственно его пароль. Далее пользователю необходимо будет отправить данные на сервер и при соответствии введенных данных сервер должен будет вернуть ключ (самый сложный вопрос), который необходимо будет поместить на локально созданный файл/файлы располагающийся в какой-либо системной папке. Предполагается также использовать запись в реестр. Также программа должна будет устанавливаться на 1 год с момента активации. После чего для запуска программы необходимо снова пройти активацию. Предполагаю реализовывать данную задачу в Visual Studio 2010.

Возможно ли в принципе такое осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это возможно. У Вас есть варианты:

- реализовать все самому;
- найти готовый продукт.

Из готовых продуктов я сталкивался с:

- [Microsoft SLP Services](http://www.microsoft.com/slps/)
- [Flexera FlexNet](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/flexnet-producer-suite-software-vendors.htm)

В обоих случаях мой работодатель шел на то, чтобы купить нужное ПО.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется что вы путаете 2 разные вещи.
Инсталляционные пакеты можно делать при помощи innosetup либо других программ.
Активаторы обычно пишутся отдельно и запускаются при первом старте ПО либо после завершения установки.